# Google Glass listing Items

Tags: android, listview, google-glass, google-gdk, cardscrollview

Lately there have been lots of changes to Google Glass GDK and I'm getting a little confused. I have a list of discovered Bluetooth devices and I want to list them with Name, address and if possible more info (as paired, last connection, etc.)

Which method would be the best to do this? ListView? Or is it true that it is no loger supported in GGlass? CardScroll? But then I have to do a bunch of Cards? Is there any other?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you really trying to do here *that is, what is the "user interaction" that you want to show)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView`s do not conform to best Glass UX practices and you should avoid them; they're difficult to use since Glass's touch-interaction model is based on horizontal motion.

It sounds like your use case is perfect for a `CardScrollView`, similar to the Settings bundle. Use one card per device and the user can scroll through them, and you'll have plenty of room to put some of the device's details, like address and pairing status, on each card as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, based on what you are telling me, I'm looking at the example at this [link](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui-widgets) to create the Cards. So basically if I want to have some organized information (More than the Name and footer) I have to create my own layout?

Comment: Yes, you can use a CardScrollView much like you do a ListView. You create a custom adapter and the inflate the layout in the getView override method. As a note ListViews where NEVER a good option on Google Glass.